# How do I include code that runs in the Constructor?

Tags: javascript

I want to create an Object Constructor, with function code that runs when I create a **new** instance, so that an instance variable is a function of the parameters passed to the Constructor.  But I want the function code to be in a prototype, so that it's not replicated on each instance.  In principle, something like:

```
function MyObject(parameter) {
    this.x = myFunction(parameter);
}
MyObject.prototype = {
    myFunction:  function(parameter) {
        console.log("Constructor run: ", parameter);
        return (parameter + parameter);
    }
};

var myInstance = new MyObject("yes");
console.log(myInstance.x);
```

The problem with the above is that at the point at which MyObject is parsed, it doesn't know about myFunction.  What am I doing wrong ?

Mike

Comment: `this.myFunction`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question?